# Element div follow mouse position

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to recreate the effect of a light beam in theatre.
In that case I want that the beam follow my mouse.

This is my code, I want that the #ligh1 el remain still at the top but the bottom portion keep follows my mouse.

Any clue?

Thanks

```js
document
  .getElementById('header')
  .addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const mouseFollow = document.getElementById('light1');
    const x = e.clientX - 25; //-25 to center div over mouse
    const y = e.clientY - 25;
    mouseFollow.style.width = x;
  });
```

```css
header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#light1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 235, 205, .5);
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  transform: scaleX(.25) skew(45deg, 0) perspective(20px) rotateX(3deg);
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div id="light1" style="width: 200px"></div>
</header>
```

Edit: I don't know why it doesnt work in code snippet but if you past your code in an html page it should work.

Comment: Your code does not work because you do not set a unit to the width.  `mouseFollow.style.width = x + 'px';`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's moving to the right as you are increasing the width is due to the transform you've applied. The width is just increasing the transforms such that the skew, rotation etc. are resulting in the sliding behavior.

If you want to achieve this with CSS I'd recommend nesting the light inside another div. Then you can have the parent div positioned on the left top corner with a rotation transform applied to it to so that as you transform the light's width you are able to transform the rotation of the parent element. I hacked around with your code a little bit to give you an idea of what I'm suggesting.

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-violet-1ulgl?file=/index.html